# Solve complex exponential equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to solve an expression of this kind (solve for $x$):

$e^{\pi i x} -e^{-\pi ix} = 2yi$

Both $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, $y$ is given. I have no clue on how to solve it analytically.

All I know is that I can rewrite this as:

$\sin(x\pi) = y$

so:

$x=\frac{\arcsin(y)}{\pi}$

But I don't know how to generate the complex solutions from this form (neither form actually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^{\pi ix}-e^{-\pi ix}=y\cdot 2i$$
$$\left( e^{\pi ix}-e^{-\pi ix} \right)e^{\pi ix}=(2iy)e^{\pi ix}$$
$$\left(e^{\pi ix}\right)^2-1=2iye^{\pi ix}$$
$$\left(e^{\pi ix}\right)^2-2iy\left(e^{\pi ix}\right)-1=0$$
$$e^{\pi ix}=\frac{-(-2iy)\pm\sqrt{(-2iy)^2-4(1)(-1)}}{2(1)}$$
$$=\frac{2iy\pm\sqrt{-4y^2+4}}{2}$$
$$=iy\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$$
$$\pi ix=\ln\left( iy\pm\sqrt{1-y^2} \right)$$
$$x=\frac{\ln\left( iy\pm\sqrt{1-y^2} \right)}{i\pi}$$

You can modify this, if you like, in several ways, especially to emphasize that $x$ is real. Note that the $\ln$ function is multi-valued, so you may get more than two values.

Comment: This is also the formula for $\arcsin$ for complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(x\pi) = y$. And you have

$$ x = \frac{(-1)^{k+1} \arcsin y + k\pi}{\pi} = \frac{(-1)^{k+1} \arcsin y}{\pi} + k, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z} $$

Comment: Actually, the OP is correct, he just didn't format the LaTeX correctly. OP, to get $\pi$, use "\pi" instead of "pi".

Comment: Oops I didn't understand that. Corrected. Thanks.